# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__tf2)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, python3, tf2, transform-listener

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i am trying to run a package built from source on ros melodic.
when i run the command i end up with this error:

```
from tf import TransformListener
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tf2_ros import TransformException as Exception, ConnectivityException, LookupException, ExtrapolationException
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_ros/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tf2_py import *
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_py/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ._tf2 import *
```

from [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/326226/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-pyinit__tf2/) i understood that it is conflicting with the python path but this solution did not work for me and i get the same error.
is there any other way to setup catkin_ws with python3?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369798/importerror:-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-(pyinit__tf2)/) by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2021-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-01-19**:
No solution, rather a comment:
Using python3 in ROS (pre-noetic) is hard! You'd have to compile everything from source to make this work properly and stumble upon hundreds of problem over and over again. A quick search for this will turn up many, many questions on that, that, in the end all (should) say:

**If you need to use python3, use ROS noetic!**

(personal opinion, but I'm 100% positive, that this will make your life a lot easier...)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-19**:\

> and stumble upon hundreds of problem over and over again

well, *hundreds*, that's a bit much perhaps, but I do agree with the advice about using Noetic if you have Python 3 requirements.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-01-19**:\

> well, hundreds, that's a bit much perhaps

well, yeah, I like to exaggerate ;-)

**Comment by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) on 2021-01-28**:
thanks guys! i tried for few days and went on solving errors one by one but ended up crashing everything the entire image and had to flash a new image from scratch :/

i will keep in mind what @mgruhler suggested from next time.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-01-29**:
could you close this issue with the appropriate resolution, if you are okay with that? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @mgruhler and @gvdhoom pointed out, yes, prenoetic with python3 will land you in so many problems. its better to switch to noetic if you need to work on python3.

---

Originally posted by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) with karma: 100 on 2021-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0